# repaint() method in JFrame or Jpanel?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, repaint

I'm new to Java and just started learning GUI components. So, I was reading Headfirst Java and there is this code explaining `paintcomponent` method of `JPanel`. It is just to change color of oval whenever user clicks on 'change colors' button. -

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SimpleGui3C implements ActionListener {

    JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleGui3C gui = new SimpleGui3C();
        gui.go();
    }

    public void go() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton button = new JButton("Change colors");
        button.addActionListener(this);

        MyDrawPanel drawPanel = new MyDrawPanel();

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, button);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, drawPanel);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        frame.repaint();
    }
}
```

**MyDrawPanel Class** -

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

//      GradientPaint gradient = new GradientPaint(70,70,Color.blue,150,150,Color.orange);

        int red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        int green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        Color startColor = new Color(red, green, blue);

        red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        Color endColor = new Color(red, green, blue);

        GradientPaint gradient = new GradientPaint(70,70,startColor,150,150,endColor);

        g2d.setPaint(gradient);
        g2d.fillOval(70,70,100,100);
    }
}
```

I got everything out of this example except for the part where we call `repaint()` method.

In the book, it was mentioned that just override the `paintcomponent` method of `JPanel` and when you call `repaint()`, it will call `paintcomponent` to render the content (since we do not call `paintcomponent` directly).

Now, I created `MyDrawPanel` class by extending `JPanel` and overridden its `paintComponent` method. Now when we put `drawPanel` widget on frame and then on mouse-click, `repint()` method is being called. But this `repaint()` method is being called using `frame` - an object of `JFrame`. As per my basic java understanding, if I'm calling a method using an object, that method has to be in that class or in some Super class. I don't see how calling `repaint()` on `frame` will trigger paint component of `MyDrawPanel`. 
I did some digging to see if `JFrame` and `JPanel` share the same hierarchy and here is what I found :

`object` --> 
`component` (has repaint method)  --> 
`container` (has paintcomponent method)-->

```
        `jcomponent` --> `jpanel`

        `window` --> `frame` --> `jframe`
```

So I thought that since `JFrame` and `JPanel` both get `paintComponent` and `repaint` methods, may be I can extend `Jframe` to create `MyDrawPanel` instead of `Jpanel` and it should work fine. But it doesn't. It compiles fine but throws runtime exception.

It's really frustrating. May be I'm not getting GUI concepts or my basics are still weak. Please let me know if I'm missing something really silly here.

Comment: Can you add the exception you're getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with `paintComponent` should really call `super.paintComponent` before performing any custom painting

Then move onto you really should read [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for a better understanding of how painting works in Swing.  `repaint` doesn't call `paintComponent` directly, it asks the `RepaintManager` to schedule a `paint` event on the event queue, which is, at some point in the future, processed by the Event Dispatching Thread, which then process the `paint` event based on the needs of the container

> So I thought that since JFrame and JComponent both get paintComponent

No, they don't.  `JFrame` (and it's parent class) do not have a `paintComponent` method

> may be I can extend Jframe to create MyDrawPanel instead of Jpanel and it should work fine"

No, you shouldn't, apart from `JFrame` not having a `paintComponent`, there is a lot more going on which can interfere with any custom painting your might try and perform on a `JFrame` and you should continue structuring your code the way it is

Comment: Then it should not even compile if JFrame doesn't have paintcomponent. It compiles fine but at run time - 



C:\javahome>java SimpleGui3C
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container
        at java.awt.Container.checkNotAWindow(Container.java:490)
        at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1091)
        at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:438)
        at SimpleGui3C.go(SimpleGui3C.java:24)
        at SimpleGui3C.main(SimpleGui3C.java:11)

Comment: I can let go everything. But how calling repaint on frame, calls paintcomponent of MyDrawPanel. This thing is bugging me.

Comment: @EolElement Add `@Override` to the `paintComponent` method in your `JFrame`, then it won't compile.  When you create a method in your class called `paintComponent`, you've just created a method.  You error is because you're trying to add a window to another window, which is an illegal operation

Comment: *"I can let go everything. But how calling repaint on frame, calls paintcomponent of MyDrawPanel. This thing is bugging me"* - This is how painting works.  A "paint request" is added to the Event Queue, which is eventually picked up and processed by the EDT which performs the actual painting. The when the frame is "painted" it also paints it's children

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer. I made some changes. Created an Instance of MyDrawPanel in SimpleGui3C . And then called repaint() on that object of MyDrawPanel. It worked fine but I see a residue image of button on top of the screen.

Comment: *"Let's start with paintComponent should really call super.paintComponent before performing any custom painting"* - `Graphics` is a shared resource across all components within a window, one of the jobs of `paintComponent` is to prepare the context for painting (by filling it with the background color)